# expandable listView Example with child listView

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I want to create an Expandable list View in which child view also having a list view.
please give me suggestion,
how to create this.

Answer (score 0):

In this you can clearly understand what is **expandable listview**

**Link**: http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial